# How do I add files to Perforce using P4?

Tags: perforce

How do I add files to Perforce using P4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what the path would be on disk, you don't need to sync anything. You can create the directory and files and then just use p4 add. For example:

1) I create a new workspace mapping a set of files from the server. Here is an example workspace:

```
Root:
  /Users/matt/p4

View:
  //depot/main/project/... //workspace/...
```

Here I am creating a 1 to 1 mapping of the files in the server //depot/main/project to my local machine at /Users/matt/p4. When I read this I read it as:

```
 //depot/main/project/... /Users/matt/p4/...
```

2) I know that the files I want to add should live in //depot/main/project/foo/bar so I create the directory and my files:

```
cd /Users/matt/p4
mkdir -p foo/bar
touch foo/bar/test.txt
```

3) Last but not least I add and submit:

```
p4 status -A
p4 submit -d "Adding a file without syncing first"
```